# Use of a Global Shaders in Unreal Engine to apply some pre-processing operations

Tags: c++, shaders, unreal, graphics-programming, level-of-detail

I'm a little experienced in Unreal Engine, but I don't know the Unreal's graphics programming from a very low level. More in details I would like to know how could use an Unreal's Global Shader to apply some pre-processing operations on to a *static mesh* and a *skeletal mesh* as for example creating different LODs. There are some tutorials the could be helpfull ? Someone has experience about pre-processing operations in Unreal ?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you read the relevant articles in the Unreal manual yet? Particularly [the section on shader development](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/shader-development-in-unreal-engine/)?

Comment: @Philipp yes but I don't understand what is a global shader. Is a shader applied to all actor present in the scene or is a shader applied to a specif actor. However, the articles don't mantion how can apply some pre-processing operations to my mesh. 

Many thanks for the answer!

Comment: I modified the post. Now it is focused only to the using of a Global Shader for pre-processing operations on to meshes